# MySQL Foreign Key syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT ( Dname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
Dnumber INT NOT NULL, 
Mgr_ssn CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
 Mgr_start_Date DATE, 
PRIMARY KEY(Dnumber), 
UNIQUE(Dname), 
FOREIGN KEY(Mgr_ssn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Ssn) 
ON DELETE SET DEFAULT ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

I am a beginner in MySQL. The command above gives me this:

> Cannot add foreign key constraint

I have tried `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`
I checked EMPLOYEE.Ssn's data type.
Please help.

Edit: My EMPLOYEE table

```
| employee | CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `Fname` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Minit` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Lname` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ssn` char(9) NOT NULL,
  `Bdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sex` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Salary` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Super_ssn` char(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Dno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Ssn`),
  KEY `Super_ssn` (`Super_ssn`),
  CONSTRAINT `employee_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Super_ssn`) REFERENCES `EMPLOYEE` (`Ssn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: You sure that FOREIGHN key is spelled with an h? or is that a typo when you pasted

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it, but now it's giving me "cannot add foreign key constraint"

Comment: "By default, table aliases are case sensitive on Unix, but not so on Windows or OS X. ...  it is best to adopt a consistent convention, such as **always** creating and referring to databases and tables **using lowercase names**. This convention is recommended for maximum portability and ease of use."       https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the MySQL docs at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html , you can't use SET DEFAULT with INNODB :

`SET DEFAULT: This action is recognized by the MySQL parser, but both InnoDB and NDB reject table definitions containing ON DELETE SET DEFAULT or ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT clauses`

Comment: Only 'ON DELETE CASCADE' works. 'ON DELETE SET NULL' or 'ON DELETE SET DEFAULT' do not work. Interesting.

Comment: I'm guessing RESTRICT would also work, so basically looks like you can't update the child record when the master record is deleted.

Comment: @MintK: to clarify your comment:  `ON DELETE SET NULL` is allowed with InnoDB as long as the foreign key column allows for null values (i.e. if the column is *not* declared with NOT NULL constraint.)